# Hapi Js File Upload Struggling

Tags: file-upload, hapi.js

today i trying to get some file upload with Hapi Js, i follow all Google Result with similarity of code.

this the code :

```html
  server.route({
        method: "POST", 
        path: `${PUBLIC_URL}${THEME_URL}/create`, 
        handler: async (request: any, reply: ResponseToolkit) => {
            console.log(request.payload.file, 'payload')
            return reply.response(request.payload)
        },
        options: {
            payload: {
                output: 'stream',
                allow: 'multipart/form-data',
                parse: false,
            }
        }
 })
```

with thats code i cant get request.payload my file or data, this is my request with postman:
[post file with postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0dCd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uqzc.png)

i got undifined at request.payload.file

if i turn payload :{parse:true} i get unsuported media types

thanks for attention

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the below version then you must be using the following syntax

@hapi/hapi: 18.x.x +

```
payload: {
     parse: true,
     multipart: {
            output: 'stream'
     },
     maxBytes: 1000 * 1000 * 5, // 5 Mb
}
```

Also, you can also try using Joi to validate your payload.

Answer (score 0):

{
method: 'POST',
path: '/upload',
options: {
payload: {
maxBytes: 209715200,
output: 'stream',
parse: true,
allow: 'multipart/form-data',
multipart: true     // <-- this fixed the media type error
},
handler: async (req, reply) => {
try {
// await importData(req.payload)
// return reply.response("IMPORT SUCCESSFULLY")

```
            const data = await req.payload;
            // let final = await importFile(data)
            // return reply.response("final", final)

            if (data.file) {
                let name = await data.file.hapi.filename;
                console.log("FIlename: " + name);

                let path = await __dirname + "/uploads/" + name;
                let file = await fs.createWriteStream(path);

                await data.file.pipe(file);
                await data.file.on('end', async function (err) {
                    // var ret = {
                    //     filename: data.file.hapi.filename,
                    //     headers: data.file.hapi.headers
                    // }

                    if (typeof require !== 'undefined')
                        XLSX = require('xlsx');

                    const workbook = await XLSX.readFile(path);
                    var sheetName = workbook.SheetNames;
                    console.log("row======>>>>");
                    await sheetName.forEach(async () => {
                        let xlData = await XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName[0]]);
                        console.log("xlData", xlData);
                        for (let i = 0; i < xlData.length; i++) {
                            console.log("if condition", xlData[i].phone)
                            const userCheck = await getUserIdService({ where: { phone: xlData[i].phone } });
                            console.log("userCheck", userCheck.data)
                            console.log("test", !(userCheck.data === null));
                            if (!(userCheck.data === null)) {
                                console.log("finally ", userCheck.data?.phone)
                                await uploadUpdateService(xlData[i], { where: { phone: userCheck.data?.phone } });

                                // return finalUpdate
                                // return reply.response("updated")

                            }
                            else if (!xlData[i].customerID) {
                                await uploadCreate(xlData[i]);
                                // return finalCreate
                            }
                        }
                    })

                })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Err----------------------' + err);
            // error handling

            return reply.response(Boom.badRequest(err.message, err))
            // return reply.response(Boom.badRequest(err.message, err));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this is for import data from excel file

Comment: Please, use proper formatting for the code.